# cannot import name '_api' from 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

I'm facing the following error while trying to import the matplotlib(Windows10 OS). I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package. Nothing seems to be working. Can somebody help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcCCF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the thread here:
https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1691
You might need to downgrade to the 3.1.3 version of mathplotlib for it to work.